# LSTM - How can I predict the status an hour before in advance?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I’m very beginner, I’m trying to design a prediction model for forecasting the status one hour ahead.I have 150 sample data, each consisting of of 24 hours of time-series data with multiple features (5 time series features, represented as x), and labels (positive or negative, represented as y)

**My question** is how to design a model to predict the status one hour in advance (or the probability of that status). In other words, can I predict the status an hour before in advance ?
I am considering using an LSTM model (Many-to-One model), but I have no idea how to design the model for predicting the status one hour before it occurs. I would like to know how to organize the dataset (its shape) for feeding it to the model.

I have a basic understanding of LSTM and experience in training with single time-series data.

I would greatly appreciate any of your brilliant ideas and advice to design it.

[image]